# is it possible to delay the validation until the user stops typing for 500ms?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Here is the codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-paper-nxjxft?file=/src/App.js

we are now validating the input on change,

and its happening immediately as the user types,

is it possible to delay the validation until the user stops typing for 500ms?

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item
        name="exampleInput"
        label={"Example Input"}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your text!",
          },
          {
            min: 2,
            max: 7,
            message: "Text must be between 2 and 7 characters",
          },
        ]}
        validateTrigger="onChange"
        required={true}
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter text" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: If you are using antd@5.9.0 or above, you can use `validateDebounce` prop in Form.Item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` functions.
try something like this :

```
 const App = () => {
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState(null);

  const handleValidation = (rule, value, callback) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId); // Clear the previous timeout, if any

    // Set a new timeout for 500ms
    const newTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      // Your validation logic here
      if (value.length < 2 || value.length > 7) {
        callback("Text must be between 2 and 7 characters");
      } else {
        callback();
      }
    }, 500);

    setTimeoutId(newTimeoutId); // Store the new timeout ID
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item
        name="exampleInput"
        label={"Example Input"}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your text!",
          },
          {
            validator: (rule, value, callback) => {
              handleValidation(rule, value, callback);
            },
          },
        ]}
        validateTrigger="onChange"
        required={true}
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter text" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```